# 2D array assignment Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let grid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]


function solveSudoku(){
    console.log("started")
    solveSudokuHelper(0,0)
    console.log(grid)
}

function solveSudokuHelper(x,y){
    // this happens when the grid is solved
    if (y>8){
        console.log("init finishing process")
        displaySodoku(grid)
    }

    // this happens when the grid is at the final row, and needs to go down a row
    if (x>8){
        solveSudokuHelper(0,y+1,grid)  
        return
    }
    if (grid[y][x] == 0){
        for (i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            if (isValid(x, y, i, grid)){
                console.log(grid, 1, i, y, x)
                grid[y][x] = i
                console.log(grid,2)
                solveSudokuHelper(x+1, y, grid)
                grid[y][x] = 0
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        solveSudokuHelper(x+1, y, grid)
    }
    return
}

function isValid(x, y, num, grid){

    // row checking
    for (col = 0; col < 9; col++){
        if (num == grid[y][col]){
            return(false)
        }
    }
    
    // column checking
    for (row = 0; row < 9; row++){
        if (num == grid[row][x]){
            return(false)
        }
    }

    // square checking
    startRow = y - (y % 3)
    startCol = x - (x % 3)

    row = startRow
    while (row <= startRow + 2){
        col = startCol
        while (col <= startCol + 2){
            if (grid[row][col] == num){
                return(false)
            }
            col += 1
        }
        row += 1
    }
    return(true)
}

solveSudoku();
```

I am trying to make something to solve a soduku, but the array assignment of values is not working. I have surrounded it with console.log statements, and I can't seem to get anywhere. This occurs at line 48.

Something to note is that I already devised this algorithm in python, so unless the console.log statements are lying to me I have narrowed it down to this.

Python code: https://github.com/owenmoogk/sudoku-bot/blob/main/main.py

My output is just the original array repeated a bunch of times. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a line by line translation of python into JS? Maybe a way to solve is to ask "which python" formulation is most likely to be mistranslated into JS. I'd speculate if I knew Python. The more customary approach is to build up from low-level pieces to higher, unit testing as you go.

Comment: Yeah ok. I mean it still really doens't make sense to me how my array doesn't change, that should be something that just works no questions asked. My one suspicion would be that the console.log statements are not logging it properly, as they execute async(ly).

Comment: Your initial array is full of zeros. I think it should have some initial values as in the python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I just forgot 'let' in my forloop and the variable scope was being messed up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let grid = [
  [0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8, 0, 0, 9],
  [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 3],
  [1, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
  [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7],
  [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0]
];

function displaySodoku() {
  console.log(grid);
}

function solveSudoku() {
  console.log("started");
  solveSudokuHelper(0, 0);
  // console.log(grid);
}

function solveSudokuHelper(x, y) {
  // this happens when the grid is solved
  if (y > 8) {
    console.log("init finishing process");
    displaySodoku();
    return;
  }

  // this happens when the grid is at the final row, and needs to go down a row
  if (x > 8) {
    solveSudokuHelper(0, y + 1);
    return;
  }

  if (grid[y][x] == 0) {
    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      if (isValid(x, y, i)) {
        grid[y][x] = i;
        solveSudokuHelper(x + 1, y);
        grid[y][x] = 0;
      }
    }
  } else solveSudokuHelper(x + 1, y);
  return;
}

function isValid(x, y, num) {
  // row checking
  for (col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
    if (num == grid[y][col]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // column checking
  for (row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
    if (num == grid[row][x]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // square checking
  startRow = y - (y % 3);
  startCol = x - (x % 3);

  row = startRow;
  while (row <= startRow + 2) {
    col = startCol;
    while (col <= startCol + 2) {
      if (grid[row][col] == num) {
        return false;
      }
      col += 1;
    }
    row += 1;
  }
  return true;
}

solveSudoku();
```

Try this code